# how to get file Count in Azure data factory and do activities based on it

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a sftp server folder from where I am copying all the child files to a file system(destination). After the copy activity is finished, I have to delete the source folder. But before deleting the source folder, I need to confirm that number of files in the source was copied to the destination folder.

Is there a way to check whether the number of files in source and destination are same, and if they are same proceed, else exit,

Thanks

Comment: whats the status here? did arunasb's answer help?

Answer (score 2):

When the copy active completed, you can open the `Succeeded` details to check whether the number of files in source and destination are same:
[image]

Details:
[image]

If you don't know how to find the details,  you can follow these steps:

**Data Factor**--**Monitor**--**Pipeline runs**, choose the pipeline:
[image]

**View acitve runs**:
[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Finding this way is fine but my requirement is different, before pipeline execution is done, I have to check the file count on both source and destination folders. If they are same I have to run the delete activity

Comment: According my experience,  we can not do that before the pipeline execution done, Data Factory won't missing the file once you have chosen in Source.

Comment: Is there any option to find out the source and destination location of copy activity which was executed already?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it with "Get Metadata" . Create "Get Metadata" dataset, add "child items", it will output an array with all names of the files, you can use length dynamic content to check what is the size of the array (number of files), or use for each to loop through all files names and check if you have identical in your other source.

Comment: any idea how to use this list of files within dataflow and join on it?